# How can I repeat my function x times in my code?

Tags: haskell, repeat

I would like to repeat the stepcells a for b times. How can I make this ?

```
play :: Generation -> Int -> Maybe Generation
play a b 
 | b < 0 = Nothing
 | b == 0 = (Just a) 
 | otherwise = Just (stepCells a)  -- do it b times
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Noughtmare suggests in [their comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72084810/how-can-i-repeat-my-function-x-times-in-my-code#comment127368184_72084810), `iterate` is a good solution to this problem. However you can also do it with manual recursion:

```hs
play :: Generation -> Int -> Maybe Generation
play a b 
 | b < 0 = Nothing
 | b == 0 = (Just a) 
 | otherwise = play (stepCells a) (b - 1)
```